# Force ASPNET Core Controller don't serialize properties on subclassed return type

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

Not sure on the best way to phrase the title. I want to return a subclassed object from a controller, but have it serialized as if it was the base object, since there are props on the subclass that I don't want to pass along to the client.

The motivation for this is that I am using Dapper, and the flattened DbPerson can come directly from the database.

Sample query:

```
var person = conn.Query<DbPerson>("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Id = 1");
```

Example...

Given I have these classes:

```
class DbPerson : Person
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    
    public override Address Address => new Address
    {
        City = City,
        State = State,
        Zip = Zip,
    };
}

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

And this controller action

```
public Person Get()
{
    // This returns a Person object, but its really a DbPerson
    return repo.Get();
}
```

I want/expect the result to be:

```
{
  "Name": "Joe",
  "Address": {
    "City": "New York",
    "State": "NY",
    "Zip": "123456"
  }
}
```

But am getting:

```
{
  "Name": "Joe",
  "Address": {
    "City": "New York",
    "State": "NY",
    "Zip": "123456"
  },
  "City": "New York",
  "State": "NY",
  "Zip": "123456"
}
```

I guess I was expecting/hoping that the Controller would know I'm trying to return the subclass, and when the `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` internally serializes, it would do so for the type on the controller.

The only work-around I have found is to make the props on the `DbPerson` internal. I suppose another approac would be to "map" the DbPerson to the Person (creating a new instance). That's less than ideal, because then I have to manage that mapping everytime I add fields.

**I'm wondering if there is a more first-class approach?**

Comment: You could you add the `JsonIgnore` attribute to those extra properties to prevent serialisation.

Comment: "var person = conn.Query<DbPerson>("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Id = 1");" What data returns  from you repo. Without this it is impossible to make any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It was tested and working properly

```
class DbPerson : Person
{
    private string _city;
    private string _state;
    private string _zip;

    public string City { set { _city = value; } }
    public string State { set { _state = value; } }
    public string Zip { set { _zip = value; } }

    public override Address Address => new Address
    {
        City = _city,
        State = _state,
        Zip = _zip,
    };
}
```

test

```
var json=
{
  "Name": "Joe",
  "City": "New York",
  "State": "NY",
  "Zip": "123456"
}

Person person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DbPerson>(json);
```

output

```
{
  "Address": {
    "City": "New York",
    "State": "NY",
    "Zip": "123456"
  },
  "Name": "Joe"
}
```